SwiftUI textfield not clearing when autocorrected
type the following into the textfield "Add nintendo switch".
"nintendo" should be autocorrected to "Nintendo" and press the "send" button.
Textfield binded state var will clear but not render as cleared in the UI when done so via the button action closure
However, the textfield will clear if done so via the onSubmit view modifier closure
Is there something I am missing to get this to work correctly?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    private func clearText() {
        print("YAHOOOO 2clear \(self.text)")
        self.text = ""
        print("YAHOOOO 2\(self.text)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Message", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                .autocorrectionDisabled(false)
                .onSubmit {
                    clearText()
                }
            
            Button(action: {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    clearText()
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Send")
            })

        }
        .padding()
    }
}

wrapping in a dispatchQueue.main.async call
using onSubmit view modifier
the UI should update and render the textfield as empty

The solution i found is forcing an update to TextField. And you don't need DispatchQueue.main.async or onSubmit.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var updater = false
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    private func clearText() {
        self.text = ""
        updater.toggle()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Message", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                .autocorrectionDisabled(false)
                .id(updater)
            
            Button {
                clearText()
            } label: {
                Text("Send")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


Here is a working solution to clear a TextField without closing the keyboard. You need to turn off autocorrection and then turn it back on.
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text = ""
    @State var fixAutocorrection = false

    
    private func clearText() {
        text = ""
        fixAutocorrection = true
        Task { fixAutocorrection = false }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Message", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                .autocorrectionDisabled(fixAutocorrection)
            
            Button {
                clearText()
            } label: {
                Text("Send")
            }
        }
    }
}

